# Assigning Image source url to a string

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.0 App
and I am wondering how i can Access the property of the Image url and assign it to a string

or something

I wrote

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
img.UriSource = pic.Source;
```

But that's not correct , 
Error:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' to
>   'System.Uri'*

How can I do such thing?

Comment: Is pic is type of `Image` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `BitmapImage` type inherits `BitmapSource` and ultimately `ImageSource`. So this will be done by casting.

```
BitmapImage img = pic.Source as BitmapImage;
```